# Wave equation in 3D solution at various positions (Kirchoff's formula)?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

A pressure disturbance in 3D progates according to 3D equation $u_{tt}=\triangle u $

Suppose at t=0, a bomb explodes creating a disturbance exactly at position x=0 and cause an initial velocity to be

$\phi(x)=0$ and $\psi(x)=1$ for $|x|\leq$1 and 0 otherwise

a) At t=10, what is the value of u at the point (10,0,0) (can leave your answer as an integral)

Answer: By Kirchoff formula:

$u(x_{0},t)=\frac{1}{4\pi t^{2}}\int\int_{dB(x_{0},t)}\phi(x)+\nabla\phi(x)(x-x_{0})+t\psi(x)dS_{x}$

$u((10,0,0),10)=\frac{1}{4\pi 10^{2}}\int\int_{dB((10,0,0),10)}10\psi(x)dS_{x}$
what I am not sure is the boundary of the integral, how can you implement $\psi(x)=1$ for $|x|\leq1$ ?

b) At $t=10$, what is the value of u at the point $x_0=(20,8,17)$? (Give a numerical value)

I think I am supposed to apply the Kirchoff's formula as above but again, not sure about the region of integration. A sphere center at $(20,8,17)$ and radius $t=10$?

c)Suppose I am at the point $x=(20,20,20)$. At what time will I feel the initial disturbance? i.e at what time $t>0$ will $u((20,20,20),t)$ be non zero.

Answer:

From Kirchoff formula, $u((0,0,0),0)$ will only influence the value of $u((20,20,20),t)$ if $|x-x_0|=t$

That is, for $(20,20,20)$ to be on the sphere center at $(0,0,0)$ with radius t, then $t=20$

Comment: In your governing equation what is $u$? It could be velocity potential or any velocity component and probably lots of other things. If the bomb explodes exactly at the origin, how is the initial disturbance distributed over $|x|\in[0,1]$. And finally, what are $\phi(x),\psi(x)$?

Comment: @PhilipRoe I believe it stands for the displacement at the point $\textbf x$ at time $t$

Comment: $\phi(x) = u(\textbf x, 0)$ and $\psi(x) = u_t(\textbf x,0)$ @PhilipRoe

Comment: I believe the answer for $b)$ would be zero no? as the point is too far away from the explosion at $t=10$ for there to be a disturbance at that point. Even my calculations are showing that the answer should be $0$?

Comment: The problem seems to have an interpretation that the bomb is of radius 1 with center at the origin. At $t=0$ the explosive moves impulsively with velocity equal to 1.0. Question (b) would certainly then have the answer zero. The propagation speed in any cartesian direction is 1.0, so that the radial propagation speed is $\sqrt{3}$ and you would feel the disturbance
at a time $t=20/\sqrt{3}$. But those answers are just common sense, and the question seems to setting up something less trivial. Are you sure this is the actual question?

Comment: is it $20/\sqrt{3}$ or $20\cdot\sqrt3$? @PhilipRoe

Comment: @felicio. Sorry! $20.\sqrt{3}$ of course

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you will find this of interest, but anyway.

Spherically symmetric solutions of the wave equation have the form$$u(r,t)=F(r-t)/r+G(r+t)/r$$ We will take G=0 because that represents an incoming wave and pick $F$ to match the initial conditions. We arrive at the solution
$$u(r,t)=\frac{(r-t)(1-H(r-1-t))}{r}$$

where $H$ is the Heaviside function. This only makes $u_t$ zero almost everywhere at $t=0$. I think this is inevitable with discontinuous initial conditions. There is no need to use the Helmholz equation.

Comment: As you have helped me in the comments I shall award you with the bounty.

Comment: Glad I could help in some way!