# Computation of a wave equation using Kirchhoff's formula.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I want to solve this wave equation in $3$-D using Kirchhoff's formula but all I've done it doesn't work. In particular I'm not able to compute the integral in Kirchhoff's formula.

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}-\Delta u=0&\text{in $\mathbb R^3 \times(0,+\infty)$}\\
u(x,0)=|x|^2 &u_t(x,0)=0, x \in\mathbb R^3.
\end{cases}$$

It is this the classical one (homogeneous problem) with $c=1$ and $F=0$ (no external force) and $u(x,0)=|x|^2$ and $u_ t(x,0)=0$.

Comment: Could you give a reference for Kirchoff's formula ?

Comment: https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220a/handouts/waveequation3.pdf

Comment: you can find Kirchoff's formula on page 15.

Comment: thank you for the answer

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2000578/wave-equation-in-3d-solution-at-various-positions-kirchoffs-formula  also in this question you can find the formula